# Xiaomi Redmi 1S: Deleted system and framework folders

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, installation, operating-system, miui

I have a Xiaomi Redmi 1S. Through Root Browser app I unfortunately deleted system and framework folders. From then onwards my phone is not getting booted up. I tried wiping and resetting my phone from recovery (holding volume up and power button), but this did not work.

I backed my data up with an app called App restore and backup. The bakcup is in my SD card.

I'm waiting for a solution...

Comment: You will need to flash a new ROM, either the one you are currently running or another one for your device. Take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device/17153#17153)

Comment: Go to your customer care of your mobile and they will repair your mobile free of cost if you are under warranty and if you are out of warranty then you will have to pay for it.

Comment: @Varun going to customer care will not solve the desired output they will simply re-flash it with the MIUI v5 software.So its better to reflash with the custom ROM previously flashed with.

Answer (score 3):

The `/system` folder contains your operative system. That is why it won't boot anymore.

Xiaomi's default MiRecovery permits only installing a ROM located in your root directory (the main folder, corresponding to location `/`) and named `update.zip`. Since you can't access your phone directly, you have to put this file in it using your computer. This will include installing a better recovery.

This instructions are for a Windows system, if you are using another OS just tell me.

---

### Step 1: Install Fastboot on your Windows system

---

Download this file, it is an installer for the strict indispensable tools you need to put files on your softbricked phone from your PC.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979

Install it and say yes both to the adb and the driver questions.

---

### Step 2: Download latest MIUI ROM for Xiaomi Redmi 1S

---

Download the last MIUI ROM for you device from the official MIUI Eglish forum. Move it to the `C:\adb` folder the installation process created.

---

### Step 3: Reload your phone to fastboot and flash CWM

---

When your device is turned off, connect it to your PC via USB and hold the power and volume down button. You should see the MiBunny operating as a mechanic to an Android robot.
Open a command prompt in Windows (Start --> cmd.exe). Type `cd C:\adb` and then `fastboot devices`. You should see an hexadecimal code followed by "device". If not, tell me in the comments.

Now download the file you find at this link, it is our recovery.
https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95747613655040280

Extract the `.img` file you find inside and rename it `recovery.img`. Place it in `C:\adb`.

In the command prompt, address this command

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

Now reboot your phone to recovery using the power and volume up buttons. You should see the new recovery.

---

### Step 4: Copy the ROM in your phone

---

While your phone is in recovery mode, type `adb devices` and you should see again a code and "device". Then move your rom `.zip` file in your `C:\adb` folder and address these commands:

```
adb shell
mount /data/
adb push nameofrom.zip /data/
```

Obviously replace `nameofrom` with the name of the zip archive of the rom you have downloaded (probably miui_HM1SWC_JHCCNBL50.0_42c35e6c1b_4.3). If you want, rename the zip to address the command with more ease.

---

### Step 5: Install the ROM

---

When the push process has succesfully finished, navigate through your phone's recovery to `install zip`, `install from internal memory` or something like that. Select the zip you just pushed. It will start installing and, after finished, your phone should boot again upon reboot.